# Can't exit airplane mode

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, airplane-mode

I sometimes have this weird behaviour

1. My phone has zero mobile network
2. I decide I should "reboot" the GSM service, and go to airplane mode
3. I want to disable the airplane mode in order to return to normal state. After a long press on power button, I do have the "device options", however nothing happens when I press **Airplane mode (airplane mode enable)**. I am stuck in airplane mode.

However this option is not [disabled (greyed out)](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23536/cant-get-out-of-airplane-mode-option-is-greyed-out). Of course, [I have a SIM](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22733/stuck-in-air-plane-mode-how-to-force-disabling-air-plane-mode), and it will be detected after a reboot.

The other options from "device options" behave normally (I can turn of sound, turn off device or reboot). It just seems this part of the screen cannot be touched anymore.

Have you experience this? Is it a known bug? How can I disable airplane mode, but rebooting?

Samsung galaxy SII with latest official Android 4.0.4

Comment: Have you tried disabling it from *Settings* (i.e. the device configuration)? Does this yield the same problem?

Comment: Did you try throwing it into the air? There is a chance it might transform into an actual airplane O:)</offtopic>

Comment: @Sid lol! maybe attach a plywood with glue to make wings, as paper wings may not work... :P </offtopic> xD

Comment: I think I've seen this once or twice on either a Nexus 7 or a Nexus 4.  Not sure how I got around it; I doubt I rebooted the device.

Comment: how long did you wait? Exiting an airplane mode can sometimes take around 3-4 minutes to get a usable connection.

Comment: The solution for me: Settings / Apps / Phone / Advanced Settings / Modify system settings: set to off. My case: Motorola G 2014, Lineage OS

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when, for whatever reason, your phone is set to **only use WiFi** to make calls in the **call preferences menu**. On Android, with Jelly Bean upgrade, some apps will alter this setting apparently. Here's the fix. Enjoy!

From home screen, access **Apps/Settings/More Settings/Wifi Calling** (Press the part to the right of the on/off button to open another menu)/**Connection Preferences**. Choose either **"WiFi Preferred"** or **"Cellular Network Preferred".** Make sure the phone **DOES NOT have "Never Use Cellular Network" selected**, or every time you shut down your WiFi or go out of range of it, you'll be listed as in Airplane Mode in the on/off menu, but not in the apps/settings/.. menus, because your cellular transceiver is **disabled** by that setting. Note: These instructions and menu layouts are specific to my Samsung Galaxy S2 with Android 4.1.XXX Jelly Bean, but can easily be adjusted to other phones.

Hope this helps, and my best to all!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a known bug?

[Yes, it is.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22503&q=airplane&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) And it seems that it's not fixed yet.

Here are some advises from me:

1. Try to change SIM card and see what happens.
2. Backup all your applications (data) and do a hard reset.
3. Backup all your applications (data) and flash unofficial (custom) firmware. Also try newer version of Android (4.1.x, 4.2.x).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, the issue 22503 seems a bit different. My phone does not go to airplane mode itself. And the menu is not greyed. 
However [comment #19](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22503#c19) is very close from what I have

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but status *New* means nobody at Android thought it deserved to be *Open*ed.

Comment: @rds anyway these bugs are connected with each other (maybe it's even the same bug). And I don't get your second statement. New issue means new issue. I don't know how to explain it. Anyway have you tried my tips?

Comment: I am with the official ROM now. What unoffial 4.0 ROM is known to fix this? As for Jelly Beans, I have recently searched, and failed to find an unofficial ROM which more advanced than "beta" for 4.1.

Comment: there are many stable roms [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1204).

Answer (score 0):

I found the only solution without deleting the System Cache and losing everything was to change to a different SIM card.

There must be some parameter that gets corrupted in Android that is associated with the SIM card. By changing the SIM must use a different set of parameters that are not corrupted.

I tried putting back the original SIM card and the problem returned. I also tried putting my original SIM card in another Android and it also worked OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem since yesterday, this post was the solution
http://www.inflightmagazine.co/?p=351

The author refers to two steps to solve the problem, I would add the following steps between Step 1 and Step 2

- Install BusyBox from the play store
- Open BusyBox after rooting, grant it superuser permissions
- Click install on the left bottom corner of the screen
- You'll be asked to use Smart Install vs Normal Install.. I chose the first option, not sure if it makes any difference if you pick the second one
- Proceed to step 2