# Moto G XT1045 is stuck in airplane mode

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, airplane-mode

My Moto G XT1045 (Android 4.4.4) is stuck in airplane mode. I did not put it into airplane mode, but in the menu shown when holding the power button it shows that it is in airplane mode, and in the phone status page in Settings it says "Radio off". However, the airplane mode icon is not shown in the status bar. I have rebooted the phone and cleared the system cache multiple times, but it has not worked.

**Edit:**  From comments(deleted to clean up)

1. Removing SIM , reinserting did not help
2. In Safe Mode also problem continues
3. Factory reset did not help
4. Device not rooted

Comment: The problem is still there in safe mode.

Comment: That did not fix it either.

Comment: Removing the sim and rebooting the phone did not fix the issue.

Comment: No (at least 15 characters)

Comment: please see if any of commands [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130530/use-adb-to-check-if-airplane-mode-is-turned-on/20135431#20135431) can be used to get out of airplane mode. Not sure if they can be run without root. Also , you can delete your comments, since they are edited into question

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/46289/168531) might help.

Comment: Or maybe [this article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/android-wont-leave-airplane-mode-71883.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely case here is that your "modem" firmware is corrupt.

**IF ON KITKAT (4.4.4)**:  I would suggest reflash of the factory modem firmware package available from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/4g-development/xt1039-moto-g-4g-stock-firmware-kxb21-t2805619) (note this link is the FULL firmware package, download and extract the 2 necessary files).

You must have working fastboot and drivers installed so that the device is recognized by `fastboot devices` when in the bootloader. Then extract the correct firmware image for your device from the link above to the directory that contains the fastboot executable, and open an elevated command prompt (Right-click and select "Run as administrator" in Windows, or perform a `sudo su` in Linux prior to starting) and change to your fastboot directory.

Enter:

`fastboot flash modem NON-HLOS.bin`
`fastboot erase modemst1`
`fastboot erase modemst2`
`fastboot flash fsg fsg.mbn`
`fastboot erase cache`
`fastboot reboot`

This will reflash the device's modem firmware. If this fails you can attempt to flash the full image to the device, instructions are in the linked post above.

**IF ON LOLLIPOP (5.0.1)**: the procedure is the same, but substitute the Lollipop modem firmware from [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/devdb/project/dl/?id=13789).

Make absolutely sure you have the correct modems, flashing the incorrect modems could result in "undesirable" effects, although your current condition isn't of much use either.